# How to write more than one line to a txt file in C

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to write a C program that validates a SIN where the numbers are read from a txt file.

I have a function (lets call it "validate") that reads from the file the validates it.
Then I got a main function, and if my validate function returned 0 the SIN is valid, otherwise it isn't. Now I don't know how to write the result unto the txt file.

EDIT - I got it to work with the following code. But I write the output to a new file. I want to write the output to the same file I read them from.

```
int main ()
{
    int p,i,n1;


    FILE *filenumbers;
    filenumbers = fopen("A3_260568619.txt", "r");
        //open the file containing SINs
    FILE *filenumbersresult;
    filenumbersresult = fopen("Results.txt", "w");
        //Open a file to write the results

    if(filenumbers==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(filenumbers, "%d", &n1) !=EOF)
    {
        p = validate(i,n1);

        if (p == 0) //If validate function is 0 then the SIN is valid
                    //otherwise, it is not valid
        {
            fprintf(filenumbersresult, "%d is valid\n", n1);
        }

        else
        {
            fprintf(filenumbersresult, "%d is not valid\n", n1);
        }
    }

    fclose(filenumbers);
    fclose(filenumbersresult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering from your problem description if the problem is not in the way you are calling _validation()_, i.e. within a loop that does not have a fail safe exit criteria.  Of course I cannot be sure, because you did not show that part :)

Comment: i posted my entire code for you to see

Comment: The easiest way of writing to the same file is writing to _another_ file and then _moving it_. There are some unintuitive issues with using the same file as input and output.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5788215/3897316.  Agreeing with @uʍopǝpısdn, it points out that you need to worry about where you are in the file.  What it doesn't explicitly mention is that when you write one character, it overwrites the character that was already there, unless you are already at the end of the file.  You seam to be changing the length of lines of the file.  That seems like more of a hassle than is necessary, especially considering that your method works, and you can delete the old file with `remove`, or a system call.